# Security reminders keep rolling in... (SUPEE-5344 & SUPEE-1533)

Tags: security, ce-1.9.1.0, patches, ce-1.7.0.1

I have several Magento installations, that I manage on behalf of our clients.
We already patched the vulnerabilities, but the warnings keep rolling in.
We just received the third warning on *all* sites.

We have two different versions deployed: 1.7.0.2 and 1.9.1.0.

When I patched the 1.9 version, I got some warnings, but I verified that the patch was applied, by checking the 'diff' in the sh file against the actual code.
Also, I could not apply the SUPEE-1533 patch, since the changes were already made in 1.9.1.0. 
I found elsewhere that the patch is only for 1.9.0.1. 
Only SUPEE-5344 figures in my /app/etc/applied.patches.list

On 1.7.0.2 it's another problem. I did manage to apply both patches, but the SUPEE-5344 is called SUPEE-5345 instead..

The warnings keep rolling in, and the clients are complaining about them.
It looks like we didn't apply the security patches, which we did.

Also: the naming of the patches are a bit .. unfortunate.
The SUPEE-5344 and SUPEE-5345 are named for their Enterprise versions: EE_1.12.0.2 and EE_1.14.1.0, even though I downloaded the Community version of the patch...

Did I miss something, when I installed the patches?
Will the warnings stop appearing if I have the correct patch names in applied.patches.list?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Even though you have installed, the notification will come. You can simply mark as read all those messages.

Also you can check the shop url here: https://shoplift.byte.nl/

If it's all fine, then there won't be any problem at all...

Comment: That is still a bit annoying, since our clients don't necessarily understand the warnings. They only see the words 'critical' and 'important'.
We log in to the backends to clear the warnings, but with several clients, it's getting quite a problem to keep clearing them every few days. 
I hope magento is finished pushing these 'warnings' now...

Comment: Can you confirm the process that you're using to clear the warnings?  There may something we can add to help ensure they stay cleared after you perform the initial reset.

Comment: The individual notices indeed kept being disabled. The problem was that the Magento Core Team issued three different notices, for the same set of patches. Also the Admin Notification system is not capable of auto-ignoring a notice, if the files are already patched.